# Find Null Values in Rows using GroupBy

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to summarize the the data, but I want to group the data first to get the NULL counts.  I can figure out how to summarize the data the way I want, but I can't seem to figure out how to translate this using a groupby function first.

Can anyone point me to the proper syntax?

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [
        ["A", None, 12,33],
        ["B", 2,3,None],
        ["B",99,None, None],
        ["A", None, None, None]
    ]
    columns = ['GROUP', 'COUNT', 'MEASURE', "BLAH"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=columns)
    null_counts = df.isnull().sum()
    null_counts[null_counts > 0].sort(ascending=False)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
group.get_group("<GROUPNAME>").isnull().sum()
```

Which results in:

```
BLAH       1
COUNT      2
MEASURE    1
dtype: int64
```

Thanks all